# How to call a js function inside a string? I am using vue js with data table

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

i am using data table. i have to return a string of button or anchor tag with click function having  record id. But it takes the event as a string.

```
 columns:[
     {   
         title: 'Action', targets: 10, data: 'id',
        "render":function( data, type, row, meta){
           return "<a @click.prevent='self.editItem("+data+")' class="btn 
               btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>";
     } 
  ]
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement any other libraries or you are customizing the original datatables? If you need there are already implemented datatables in vue2 like: https://github.com/zhaobao/vue-table

Comment: It is working fine without self. but i have to define the scope also.

Comment: Share your all code ?

Comment: Try this `"<a @click.prevent='self.editItem("+data+")' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Edit</a>"`

Comment: already tried. not working Thanks for reply

Comment: but now i am doing this by adding event listener.